# usar proxy con phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, proxy

les describo mi situación. Tengo un sistema que envia correos via phpmailer pero quisiera ahora hacerlo por medio de proxy. Entonces mi duda es como configurar el proxy para que funciones.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->IsSMTP();                                
    $mail->Host = 'xxxx';     
    $mail->Port = 'xxx';                                
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                         
    $mail->Username = 'xxxxx';                   
    $mail->Password = 'xxxxx';                 
    $mail->SMTPSecure = '';                        
    $mail->From = 'xxxxxx ';         
    $mail->FromName = ;               
    $mail->AddAddress(); 
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;                           
    $mail->IsHTML(true);                            
    $mail->Subject =; 
    //An HTML or plain text message body
    $mail->Body = ;
```

este es mi código no sé si en alguna parte del $mail lo tengo que poner o no tiene soporte.

Muchas gracias.